# Onclick positioning the datatable on top of the table.

Tags: javascript, java, css

Chrome it is working fine. But in IE its is sometimes positioning in the middle of the table when user clicks the bottom page links.

Comment: Could you demonstrate this behavior with a small app, please?

Comment: This sounds like a css question, how does this relate to `javascript` or `java`?

Comment: Yes. I know. I was trying by css I couldn't achieved. That's why i tried with java script. Still nothing positive.